# Problemas com DateTime no Javascript com C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Pessoal tenho uma classe que recebe uma data inicio e final vinda de um Javascript:

```
public object getTime(DateTime inicio, DateTime fim) { ... }
```

Estou passando as datas assim pelo Javascript:

```
$.getJSON(`services/api/tempo/getTime/${start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}/${finish.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}`) { ... }
```

Mas preciso passar desta forma:

```
$.getJSON(`services/api/tempo/getTime/${start.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')}/${finish.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')}`) { ... }
```

Mas desta forma está dando erro

```
GET http://localhost/services/api/tempo/getTime/2020-06-02T14:10/2020-06-02T14:20 400 (Bad Request)
```

Alguem já enfrentou algo parecido? Poderiam, por favor, ajudar com este problema?

Comment: Erro aonde, no front no back? Qual mensagem de erro? Fez um console.log de start.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm') e de finish.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm') ?

Comment: Erro no front, editei a pergunta e adicionei o erro.

Comment: `error is not defined` já diz, você esta tentando acessar uma variavel chamada error que nem foi declara, logo tua mensagem de erro não tem nada haver com date.format e nem com DateTime, tem haver com uma variavel solta não definida e claro, os códigos apresentados na pergunta não tem relação alguma com isto.

Comment: O problema mesmo é o primeiro erro. Este error é uma var que eu tirei do codigo e esqueci de tirar do retorno. Mas o problema mesmo é aquele bad request. Este Bad Request só acontece quando eu utilizo a data desta forma informada.

Comment: Ok, esta dando bad request, signfica que o depurador esta desligado ou que você não esta olhando o console de rede do DevTools ou não esta olhando no visualstudio (se o teste for em local) as exceptions, não tem como advinharmos, outra coisa, eu fiz duas perguntas e vou ser obrigado a repeti-las: Fez um console.log de start.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm') e de finish.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm') ? O q eles retornam? Entenda q pra te ajudar vc precisa fornecer esses detalhes, afinal é o minimo. Fico no aguardo pra te ajudar.

Comment: Fiz sim retorna as datas 2020-06-02T16:30... Fiz o encode URI citado abaixo e retornou 2020-06-02T16%3A01, mas ianda está com bad request.

Comment: Tá, mas no VisualStudio, o breakpoint do erro exibe os detalhes no momento? É gerado a exception ou não? Como eu já disse, e já lhe fiz 4 perguntas q vc não respondeu nenhuma, dê os detalhes, não podemos adivinhar detalhes importantes

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente falta o "escape" na URL, porque alguns valores na URL devem ser codificados, isso deve resolver:

```
let a = encodeURIComponent(start.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'));
let b = encodeURIComponent(finish.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'));

$.getJSON(`services/api/tempo/getTime/${a}/${b}`) { ... }
```

Comment: Fiz o encode URI citado retornou 2020-06-02T16%3A01, mas anda está dado bad request 400.